# Cant store find the shortest path in the dijkstra algorithm

Tags: python, data-structures, shortest-path, dijkstra

I have implemented a dijkstra algorithm that calculates the shortest distance for every node from the start node, but I am not able to retrieve the shortest path for these nodes. I watched a youtube video, and then tried to implement the steps that he did in python. I did not follow a specific psuedocode. Also, if anybody could please tell me if there is anything wrong with my code.

```
def dijkstra(start_id: int,end_id:int,graph:Dict):
    '''
    TODO: Implement dijkstra, change the parameters if you wish so.
    '''
    #make a list for all of the paths
    paths = []
    # Is a list for all of the visited nodes 
    visited_nodes = []
    # make a table that stores all of the values of the nodes
    table = {v:float("inf") for v in graph}
    # Set the start id value in the table to 0
    table[start_id] = 0
    # Make the minimum that is going to be compared with equal to inifinity in the start
    minimum = float("inf")
    # The path should contain the start id at the start
    path = [start_id]
    # Make a while statement that the operation keeps going until every node is visited 
    while end_id not in visited_nodes:
        # Explore the edges of the node
        for edge in graph.get(path[-1]):
            #if edge == end_id:
            # If there is only one element in the path
            if len(path) <= 1:
                # We are going to compare it directly with itself not any before nodes
                if graph[path[-1]][edge] < table[edge]:
                    table[edge] = graph[path[-1]][edge]
            # This is the normal conditions         
            if len(path)> 1:
                # Compare the weight of this edge + the weigh of the previous edge 
                if graph[path[-1]][edge] + table[path[-2]] < table[edge]:
                    table[edge] = graph[path[-1]][edge] + table[path[-2]]
        # We then add the node to its edges were explored to the visited list
        visited_nodes.append(path[-1])
        # This is just added to be able to add the last node that was not explored
        if len(visited_nodes) < len(graph)-1:
            # Now we choose the next node to be explored, by looping through all the nodes in the set
            for node in table:
                # Only if the node is not in the visited list it will be explored
                if node not in visited_nodes:
                    if table[node] < minimum:
                        minimum = table[node]
                        minimum_node = node
            path.append(minimum_node)
        else:    
            # Will add the last node that was not added 
            for node in table:
                if node not in visited_nodes:
                    path.append(node)
        # print(minimum_node)
    paths.append(path)
    return table
```

I have tried to implement the dijkstra algorithm in my own way, but the task that I am solving requires me to return the shortest path between two nodes

Comment: *"implement the dijkstra algorithm in my own way"*: where is the priority queue?

Comment: Do I always have to use the priority queue method for the dijkstra algorithm?